# Overriding \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price

Tags: magento2, override-model

I'm implementing product price calculation based on a formula that uses customizible options in Magento 2 (ver. 2.3.1). I added some code to _applyOptionsPrice() to "Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php and it works like a charm. Now I want to take my code out of magento code, and implement it as an custom module, but as much as I try I can not get it to work as it's suppose to do.

Here is my code:

in app/code/ABPPRK/ModulePrice/registration.php:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'ABPPRK_ModulePrice',
__DIR__
);
```

in app/code/ABPPRK/ModulePrice/etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price" type="ABPPRK\ModulePrice\Model\Price" />
</config>
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ABPPRK_ModulePrice" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

And finally app/code/ABPPRK/ModulePrice/Model/Price.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace ABPPRK\ModulePrice\Model;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price 
{

    public function getFinalPrice($qty, $product)
    {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Of course the return of the method to override (getFinalPrice) should not be that one. This is just a simple implementation to test with xdebug that does not work, as neither the real code.

There are no errors during "bin/magento setup:di:compile". And I can tell that command is considering my module because at some past point it gave the error:

"Warning: Declaration of ABPPRK\ModulePrice\Model\Price::getFinalPrice() should be compatible with Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price::getFinalPrice($qty, $product)"

What is missing here? I've followed all the tutorials I've found about overriding class methods but Iven't found anyone specific for this method. :-(

Thanks in advance,
Armando.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add sequence in module.xml ,
may be you need to load catalog and sales modules before your's

Comment: Please add more details about this.

Comment: Check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html

Comment: May be you new to add <module name="Magento_Catalog"/> <module name="Magento_Sales"/>  in module.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
public function getFinalPrice(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price $price, $qty, $product)
```

as your function signature.

The first argument when injecting functions in magento is always the subject class, so you can call the subject classes functions.